# Adding All The numbers in a DOB?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I add all the numbers in a Dob together? For example; 080789 = 32 but in a function which asks the user for their DOB?

I have this already:

```
me = int(input("enter your dob"))

def dob(me):
    dob = []
    count = 0
    me = str(me)
    for i in range(len(me)):
        dob.append(me[i])
    for i in range(len(dob)):
        dob[i] = int(dob[i])
        count += dob[i]
    total = count + me
print(total)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `sum(map(int, '080789'))`

Comment: @senshin Won't work if the user enters, e.g., `08/07/89`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dob` function in your code is never called, and `total` is printed outside the function without having `total` returned from the function. From what I can see, you also try to convert the `input` to `int` directly, and then converting it back to `string` inside the function. Which is not needed.

Here is a simple code that could do what you want.

```
def dob(me):
    # Create a list of ints containing only the
    # numbers from the user input
    me = [int(s) for s in me if s.isdigit()]

    # Add all numbers in me and print it.
    total = sum(me)
    print(total)

# Get user input and store it to answer
answer = input("enter your dob")

# Call dob function and pass it the answer / input
dob(answer)
```